# Manifoldcf documentum crawling slowness

Tags: java, elasticsearch, solr, open-source, manifoldcf

We are crawling data from DCTM repository using ManiFoldCF documentum connector and writing the crawled data to MongoDB. Crawling triggered with throttling value 500.But crawling speed is very slow per minute connector is fetching only 170 documents. The server where MCF installed is configured with enough memory with 8 logical cores (CPU). Can someone help us here to improve crawling speed?

Answer (score 0):

better tuning the crawling Database(PostgreSQL ) is good start.

there is some reference you can use:
https://manifoldcf.apache.org/release/release-2.13/en_US/performance-tuning.html